# What does two consecutive apostrophes mean in Haskell and Plutus?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, haskell

I have noticed the frequent appearance of two consecutive apostrophes in Haskell code.

Like this:

```
newtype Date = Date Integer
data EndDate = Fixed Integer | Never
unstableMakeIsData ''Date
unstableMakeIsData ''EndDate
```

What does `''` mean in haskell?

Answer (score 3):

The apostrophe(s) in Haskell (and thus Plutus) are part of the name; they do not hold any specific meaning.

Haskell as a functional programming language borrows from mathematical notation. An apostrophe on a variable name conveys that it is somewhat related to another variable (without or with more apostrophes).

Imagine a simple function that adds three values. You could write these several ways.

```
addThreeNumbers a b c = a + b + c
addThreeNumbers' a b c = b + c + a
addThreeNumbers'' a b c = b + a + c
addThreeNumbers''' a b c = c + a + b
```

and so on. The result will always be the same.

---

The apostrophes in your example are, however, not of the same type as the prefix data types. This is an indicator that [template haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell) is being used.

Comment: but in my case, unstableMakeIsData is a function name and ''Date is not defined before. The apostrophe(s) is a prefix not suffix, I think It might be different.

Comment: I found your example in this commit: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/commit/01f14933a8fc35e02aaec4cedfeac6dc5396b382 -- take a look at the Instances.hs

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The apostrophes in front of the type hint at template haskell

Comment: Thank you a lot!